# JQuery if statement for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I have a jQuery that runs through multiple tables on my pages and totals up items from those tables. However, as the following main section of my jquery just goes through each table I was wondering if I can limit the tables based on div class as it is running the query through the header as well.

```
$('table').each(function(){
  var tr = {};
  $(this).find('tr').each(function(){
  var key = $(this).find('td.job_code').text();
  var val1 = toSeconds($(this).find('td.hrs').text());
  //var val = +$(this).find('td.hrs').text().split(':')[0];
  if(tr[key]){
    tr[key]+=val1;
  }else{
    tr[key]=val1; 
  } 
});
```

Maybe with something like?

```
if($('div).class == "timecard"){}
```

Comment: [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/). You would need something like the following: `if($('div').hasClass('timecard')) { ... }`...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the statement _"limit the tables"_ a little more. I'm a little fuzzy on what you're asking. You don't want to search every table in the document? or you don't want to search the `<thead>` section of each table?

Comment: You should provide some HTML with this since your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.hasClass()` like so:

```
if($('div').hasClass('timecard')){
  //do something
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hasClass()` for your test -

```
if( $('div').hasClass('timecard') ) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want, but if you want all **tables** which have the div in them:

```
$('table').each(function(){
    if( $(this).find('div.timecard').length!==0){
         /* something */ 
    }
}
```

Or, as recommended in the comments by Bill:

```
$('table').has('div').each(function(){  /* something */ })
```

Comment: You could do this a little more cleanly with `$('table').has('div').each()`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this is what you want

```
$('.timecard > table tr td').each(function(){
```

See the example below

http://jsfiddle.net/22bn8/

Comment: I think this is the wrong way around. This gets the tables in the divs, I believe he wants the tables who contain the div. But I can be wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

The best way you can do it is by using `.attr()`

```
if ( $("#yourId").attr("class") == "yourclass" ) {
    // Your function here 
}
```

Here is a demo **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t3mh/)**

Comment: Downvote for two reasons: if I have another class to  `#yourid` (eg: `class="yourclass otherclass"` this will fail. 2nd reason is you are trying to mimic jQuerys `hasClass()`

Comment: if you prefer this method, you should go all native on this: `/\byourclass\b/.test(document.getElementById('yourid').classname)`, a regex with wordboundery